# Is there a way to edit the source code of the JIRA Issue Collector?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am trying to allow users to create issues from a webpage, just like the Issue Collector. The problem is, there are only three templates provided for the collector and none of them are quite right.

What I want is to have three required fields that then combine to become the description. (Similar to how the first template has "what do you like" "what do you not like" which both go in the description)

The problem is there's no obvious way to edit the popup's contents.

Is there any way I can get at the source code of the collector to create my own modified version? Alternatively, if I just copy the html of the popup using inspect element could I create a working clone?

EDIT: Well, I've managed to get at the source code using a java decompiler, but now I haven't got a clue how to put it back together again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a paid license for JIRA? If so, Atlassian will *give* you a copy of the source code.

From their FAQ's

> 5. **After an order has been placed, how and when can the license key and source be accessed?**
>
> Access to your license key(s) and any
>   applicable source code is provided only after the successful receipt
>   and processing of your payment. Once payment is received, the Billing
>   and Technical contact specified on the order can log into their My
>   Atlassian account, and view all corresponding license keys.

And instructions on [how to "put it all back together"](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/jira-architecture/building-jira-from-source) :)

Then you are free to customize to your heart's content.

Of course, you'll need to re-customize every time there's an update from Atlassian ...

See also [this post on Atlassian's wiki](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/231891/changing-jira-source-code)